# Facebook - change background image of facebook app

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to change the background image of my facebook app? I tried adding a body tag in the css and set a background image. But the change is not reflected.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your whole application in one div and define a background-image for the div.

This is IMHO the best workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Its only possible by using extensions for your browser; for eg; use http://www.facebook.com/chameleontom